# Incorrect array type being passed to a subroutine

Tags: arrays, sorting, qb64

So I'm not overly familiar with QB64 and the documentation is sparse so I'm having trouble.

```
TYPE character
FName AS STRING * 12
LName AS STRING * 12
ID_Num AS INTEGER
Year AS STRING * 2
GPA AS DOUBLE
END TYPE
DIM LENGTH AS INTEGER

LENGTH = 11

REDIM chars(0) AS character

CLS

n$ = "names1.txt"

OPEN n$ FOR INPUT AS #1

k = -1

WHILE (NOT (EOF(1)))
k = k + 1

REDIM _PRESERVE chars(k) AS character
INPUT #1, chars(k).FName, chars(k).LName, chars(k).ID_Num, chars(k).Year, 
chars(k).GPA

WEND
CLOSE #1


CALL sortArray(chars(), LENGTH)

SUB sortArray (score() AS INTEGER, SIZE AS INTEGER)

DIM x AS INTEGER
DIM y AS INTEGER
DIM COMPS AS INTEGER

x = 0
y = 0
COMPS = SIZE - 1

WHILE y < COMPS
    x = 0
    WHILE x < COMPS
        IF score(x) > score(x + 1) THEN
            CALL swap2(score(), x)
        END IF
        x = x + 1
    WEND
    y = y + 1
    WEND

    END SUB



    SUB swap2 (score() AS INTEGER, x AS INTEGER) 
DIM temp AS INTEGER
temp = score(x + 1)
score(x + 1) = score(x)
score(x) = temp
END SUB
```

I'm receiving an error - "Incorrect array type passed to sub" on the following line:

```
CALL sortArray(chars(), LENGTH)
```

I am assuming that since I used REDIM above, that the sub isn't processing it appropriately, but I'm not really sure how to fix that. Ultimately I'm trying to read in a file to an array, sort that array and then print it out to the user. Currently I'm stuck as to how to actually sort the array.

Any help will be appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: What kind of score are you trying to sort on?  There's no score property in the `character` type.  Do you mean to sort on the GPA property?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're passing the array `chars()`, containing elements of the type `character`, but your subroutine only accepts an array containing elements of type `INTEGER`.

What you need is `score() AS character` (better named `chars() AS character`), and you can sort based on whatever criteria you desire (e.g. `IF score(x).GPA > score(x+1).GPA THEN ...`). Also, there is a [built-in `SWAP` statement](http://www.qb64.net/wiki/index.php/SWAP) that will swap things for you, so there's no need to write your own (unless you're supposed to).

Answer (score 0):

Here is your code (heavily modified) where:

1)The UDTs are properly declared.
2)The redim only works when $dynamic declared.
3)The "bubble sort" is shorter.

```
REM $DYNAMIC
TYPE character
    FName AS STRING * 12
    LName AS STRING * 12
    ID_Num AS INTEGER
    Year AS STRING * 2
    GPA AS DOUBLE
END TYPE
DIM chars(0) AS character
n$ = "names1.txt"
OPEN n$ FOR INPUT AS #1
WHILE NOT EOF(1)
    k = k + 1
    REDIM _PRESERVE chars(k) AS character
    INPUT #1, chars(k).FName, chars(k).LName, chars(k).ID_Num, chars(k).Year, chars(k).GPA
WEND
CLOSE #1
CALL SortArray(chars(), k)
END
SUB SortArray (score() AS character, SIZE AS INTEGER)
' bubble sort
FOR x = 1 TO SIZE
    FOR y = x + 1 TO SIZE
        IF score(x).GPA > score(y).GPA THEN
            SWAP score(x), score(y)
        END IF
    NEXT
NEXT
END SUB
```